The limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}$ exists implies $f\left( x\right)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$?

Let $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$. For any ${a}_{n} < 0 < {b}_{n}$ with $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}{a}_{n} = \mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}{b}_{n} =0$, $\left\{  {a}_{n}\right\} , \left\{  {b}_{n}\right\}$, the limit $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}\frac{f\left( {b}_{n}\right)  - f\left( {a}_{n}\right) }{{b}_{n} - {a}_{n}}$ exists. Can we prove that  $f\left( x\right)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$?

My attempt: we can easily show that the limit $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}\frac{f\left( {b}_{n}\right)  - f\left( {a}_{n}\right) }{{b}_{n} - {a}_{n}}$ does not depend on the choice of $a_n,b_n$.
Let the limit be $A$.
Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$, for $n\geq N$,
$$-\epsilon(b_n-a_n)<f(b_n)-f(a_n)-A(b_n-a_n)<\epsilon(b_n-a_n)$$
To verify the differentiability of $f$ at $x=0$, choose $a_n=-b_n$, then
$$-\epsilon(2b_n)<f(b_n)-f(-b_n)-A(2b_n)<\epsilon(2b_n)$$
To estimate $f(-b_n)$, we use continuity, for $n$ large,
$$-\epsilon(2b_n)+f(0)-\epsilon<f(b_n)-A(2b_n)<f(0)+\epsilon+\epsilon(2b_n)$$
But we could not divide $2b_n$ to take limit...Any ideas?
